# how can I use a texture larger than my displacement mesh to make 3d maps in blender

Tags: mesh

How can I use a texture larger than my displacement mesh to make 3d maps in Blender?

I'm a beginner at this, I didn't find anything about it.

The texture I want to use is an old map with a coordinate grid and the tiff occupies just a part of this texture

[image]

Comment: First idea: crop the image in software like Gimp or Photoshop to get rid of the parts you do not want? Second idea: scale the UVs in the _UV Editor_ so that they only use the part you want them to use? If that's not what you want, I do not understand the question... actually I do not even understand what you mean with "the tiff occupies just a part of this texture". Are these two images on top of each other? Is the heightmap a TIFF above a JPEG or a PNG? What does this sentence mean?

Comment: what I want to do is basically this: see here, at minute 32:12 and then at minute 43:16 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waZF96-lqso. before and after

Comment: 1. Do not rely on external links to videos to show your issue, use screenshots and detailed explanations. 2. Well, looks to me as if the UVs were set up so that only the inner part of the mesh uses the heightmap. But this is a video of over one hour. Are they not showing how they did it? I'm not willing to watch the whole video to find that out.

Comment: Do you want your 3D map in geometry, or just visualized in an image?

Answer (score 2):

Unwrap your mesh in *Edit* mode (<kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*), in the *UV Editor* window put the mesh over the image, scale and rotate the UV if necessary, give your mesh a *Displace* modifier with *Coordinates > UV*:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, right click > *Shade Smooth*, play with the *Strength* value of the modifier to choose its height:

[image]